# Would questions looking for parables/tales be on-topic of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would questions looking for parables/tales be on-topic of this site? I'm not sure if this falls to the first bullet of [What qualifies as a "myth"?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Traditional myths, i.e. stories of great cultural significance such as the labors of Hercules or King Arthur's exploits are on-topic
> - Folklore is on-topic
> - Stories from religious scripture are on-topic; the doctrines espoused by a religion are off-topic
> - Myths that exist solely within a fictional work (e.g., Star Wars, Game of Thrones) are off-topic, though you may be able to ask about
>     them on another site such as SciFi.SE

The sample of the question is below:

---

I am translating my article to English, which heavily uses the [Blind men and an elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant). Since the metaphor is important, I am looking for an alternative tale that is more well-known in the West, especially in the US. Do you know any of them?

> A group of blind men heard that a strange animal, called an elephant, had been brought to the town, but none of them were aware of its shape and form. Out of curiosity, they said: "We must inspect and know it by touch, of which we are capable". So, they sought it out, and when they found it they groped about it. In the case of the first person, whose hand landed on the trunk, said "This being is like a thick snake". For another one whose hand reached its ear, it seemed like a kind of fan. As for another person, whose hand was upon its leg, said, the elephant is a pillar like a tree-trunk. The blind man who placed his hand upon its side said, "elephant is a wall". Another who felt its tail, described it as a rope. The last felt its tusk, stating the elephant is that which is hard, smooth and like a spear.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While they are not "mythology", traditional parables *can* fit on Myth.SE under "folklore". Be sure to use an appropriate folklore tag, however.

In your case, I think the blind men and elephant parable is *already* pretty widely known in the west. I'd be surprised if there's a comparable western parable that's more well known. That said, it doesn't hurt to ask whether there's a similar tale in English or some other tradition's folklore, of course.